# How to set access IP with remote mysql by cpanel

Tags: php, mysql, remote-access

I do not know  how to set Access Host.
I use mobile network so not have fixed IP.I find a solution but not really know
"For example, to allow access from all IP addresses that begin with 192.68.0, enter 192.68.0.%."Have other solution?

thanks a lot.

Comment: `%` should give all IPs access.

Answer (score 0):

In the cPanel of your website go to MySQL Remote and in the add hosts field enter "%". Although this is not secure it will allow remote connections from all IP's as yours is dynamic and likely to change. Then in the client on your local machine enter in your servers IP and when you add the user account and password you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot.Only add this 192.68.0.%?I added this(192.68.0.%) before but also can not access remote mysql.